# How can I hide the title as default in the new version of fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

The previous version had a `'titleShow': false,` setting, however it seems to have been removed for the new version.

I know I can hide it programmatically using jquery but I'd prefer to use a built in feature to remove it??

Comment: If its the fancybox-title-over you wan't to hide you probably could add a css rule in your page, like #fancybox-title-over { display:none; }

Comment: Yeh I've had to do it that way, but it means the calculated margin at the top and bottom are different.  I would have preferred it to be an option like in the previous version so margins are calculated based on showing the title or not..

Comment: Well I'm looking at the API spec for version 1.3+ and it says that titleShow: bool still works http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: That's the old documentation though.  The new documentation is at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs .

It definitely doesn't work, I have two implementations running, one on each version and titleShow only works on the previous version.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can disable title helper -

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: { 
        title: null
    }
});
```

Comment: works for me too; you could also use - "helpers: {title: false}" - Janis cannot be wrong, after all he is fancybox's creator  :)

Comment: @Janis It only works if helpers is the first option of fancybox. When I have openEffect and closeEffect first it does not hide the title, but when I move it up to the top it works.

Answer (score 3):

Top disable the title;

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: { 
        title: **false**
    }
});

Answer (score 2):

I used this css to hide title:

```
#fancybox-title-float-wrap {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the top answer actually does work if you have a read through the comments on it. @Janis (the person who answered the question) is actually the creator of fancybox so wouldn't want to doubt him!

Answer (score 1):

In CSS file: give `visibility:hidden` in

```
fancybox-title-float-left, 
fancybox-title-float-main,
fancybox-title-float-right,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just delete the title attribute from the the anchor tag there is not title shown. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: I pass in the unique id of the item clicked as the title so that on the 'afterShow' event I can perform an ajax call to save an audit of the click

Answer (score 0):

I had to rip out the line of code that appends the title as I could find no way of doing it using the API..

```
c.appendTo("over"===b.type?a.inner:"outside"===b.type?a.wrap:a.outer)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the .css file, change:

```
.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

to

```
.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Tested on 2.0.5.

Answer (score -1):

title: null

I have checked it and it works for me.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some more details to your answer?